# Hybris Jacoco Sonar include allwebtests to result report

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to integrate `Jacoco` into `Hybris`and send the report to `Sonar`. I managed to achieve that `Hybris` sends report to `Sonar`, but it doesn't include **ant allwebtests** target in the result report. Here is **acc-ant-sonar.xml** which I created and put in the following path :

{HYBRIS_CONFIG_FOLDER}/customize/ext-accelerator/acceleratorservices/resources/acceleratorservices/ant/acc-ant-sonar.xml

```
<project name="acc.ant.sonar" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="${ext.acceleratorservices.path}/lib/jacocoant.jar"/>
    </taskdef>


    <target name="jacocoalltests" description="runs allstests with jacoco attached">

        <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                      append="true"
                      output="file"
                      destfile="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/junit/jacoco.exec"
                />

        <property name="testclasses.packages" value="${testclasses.packages}"/>
        <ant dir="${platformhome}" target="alltests" inheritrefs="false">
            <property name="standalone.javaoptions" value="${agentvmparam} ${standalone.javaoptions}"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <target name="jacocounittests" description="runs allstests with jacoco attached">

        <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                      destfile="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/junit/jacoco.exec"
        />

        <property name="testclasses.packages" value="${testclasses.packages}"/>
        <ant dir="${platformhome}" target="unittests" inheritrefs="false">
            <property name="standalone.javaoptions" value="${agentvmparam} ${standalone.javaoptions}"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <target name="jacocointegrationtests" description="runs allstests with jacoco attached">

        <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                      destfile="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/junit/jacoco-it.exec"
        />

        <property name="testclasses.packages" value="${testclasses.packages}"/>
        <ant dir="${platformhome}" target="integrationtests" inheritrefs="false">
            <property name="standalone.javaoptions" value="${agentvmparam} ${standalone.javaoptions}"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

</project>
```

I wanted to add target **jacocoallwebtests** in this file, but `Hybris`doesn't contain such  target. So, how could I include **allwebtests** to `Jacoco` report which will be be send to `Sonar`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same targets to execute web tests as non web tests. You have only to set `testclasses.web` to `true`. Example for **jacocoallwebtests**:

```
<target name="jacocoallwebtests" description="runs allwebtests with jacoco attached">
    <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                  append="true"
                  output="file"
                  destfile="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/junit/jacoco.exec" />
    <property name="testclasses.packages" value="${testclasses.packages}"/>
    <property name="testclasses.web" value="true"/>
    <ant dir="${platformhome}" target="alltests" inheritrefs="false">
         <property name="standalone.javaoptions"
                   value="${agentvmparam} ${standalone.javaoptions}" />
    </ant>
</target>
```